# List of GPO's

Tags: powershell, group-policy

How do I get a list of GPO's applied against a machine in a Win2k8 environment remotely?

I would prefer a powershell solution, but anything will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPRESULT

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160(WS.10).aspx

Works against remote computers.

In windows 2003 we had to type GPRESULT only in the command line in order to view the Applied Group polices however in windows server 2008 we need to type the /R switch after the gpresult.

Answer (score 0):

GPResult as Rob mentioned is an excellent way of doing this.  You can however also get at this information via the WMI RSP Classes.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375082(VS.85).aspx for further information as this may allow you to do this in powershell against all of your machines in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3rd party tools that supposedly do it in PowerShell here:  http://www.sdmsoftware.com/freeware

Particularly:  Out-SDMRSOPLoggingReport: Creates and XML or HTML Group Policy Results report

Answer (score 0):

The Group Policy Management Console can also do this in a GUI manner, and has nice features such as letting you see exactly which policy each setting is coming from.

Answer (score -3):

List Group Policy Object using PowerShell

http://winplat.net/post/2013/07/04/List-Group-Policy-Object-using-Powershell.aspx

Comment: We expect ServerFault answers to contain more content than just a link. Please feel free to edit your answer to be more comprehensive.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.